# ng-class doesn't work with kendo rtl class

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing a problem with using ng-class with kendo rtl

This is my html code

```
<div ng-class="isRtl ? 'k-rtl' : ''">
    <div kendo-grid="mainGrid" options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="select(data, dataItem)"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I kendo renders the grid befor my ng-class gets compiled so it adds inline style to the grid as if it is ltr so could anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: What do you mean by *ng-class gets rendered* please elaborate more?

Comment: The right syntax of ngClass should be `ng-class="{'k-rtl': isRtl, '': !isRtl}"`

Comment: @KostasSiabanis even what OP has, is valid syntax. It works :) , `ng-class` expects either expression or json object, read [docs here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js#L154-L162)

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry I mean gets compiled

Comment: @user3260672 still I don't understand, whats matter with class `k-rtl`, is anything kendo specific? please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking question

Comment: @PankajParkar interesting.. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just give it a try

```
<div ng-class="{'k-rtl': isRtl}">
    <div kendo-grid="mainGrid" options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="select(data, dataItem)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is point to assign a class from `$timeout`? Unnecessarily it will run one more digest cycle..

Comment: @KostasSiabanis, Yes.. I realized the mistake I made.